# xpanes で並列実行したい

Tags: tmux

[xpanes](https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes) は複数の対象に対するコマンドを、その分だけ tmux pane を開きながら実行することができるツールです。

デフォルトでは、それぞれの pane に対するコマンドの実行は、一つ一つ実行されています:

1. pane を対象分だけ用意する
2. 各 pane に対して、ひとつひとつ、実行するべき command を送り込む。

2 の処理が並列実行できたらいいなと思いました。

#### 質問

- xpanes で各開かれた pane に対しての処理を並列実行することはできますか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ソース](https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes/blob/3fcdbfdaf0c0cb22cbed92e7d3208b79fb60a1ed/bin/xpanes#L492)を読むとpaneに対して順番にコマンドを投げるだけのようなので、完全に同時にコマンドを投げ込むことは不可能と思いました。(並列実行はできていますが、質問の意図としては同時に、ということですよね)

```sh
# Send command to the all the panes in the target window.
xpns_send_commands() {
  local _window_name="$1"  ; shift
  local _index_offset="$1" ; shift
  local _repstr="$1"       ; shift
  local _cmd="$1"          ; shift
  local _index=0
  local _pane_index
  for arg in "$@"
  do
    _pane_index=$(( _index + _index_offset ))
    ${TMUX_XPANES_EXEC} send-keys -t "${_window_name}.${_pane_index}" "${_cmd//${_repstr}/${arg}}" C-m
    _index=$(( _index + 1 ))
  done
}
```

Comment: ソースをいじって試してみた結果、 tmux の send-command 自体に、 tmux 側で排他制御かかっているっぽいな、と思うに至りました。